# cant acess my old files because ecryptfs

Tags: dual-boot, ecryptfs

Just yesterday, I installed windows 7 when I had Ubuntu but on a different HDD. When I finished, I booted into my Ubuntu HDD but it came up saying that grub has failed.

So I reinstalled Ubuntu to find my files locked with `ecryptfs`. I tried all methods I could find so far including the Ubuntu live cd method and the terminal method on my newly installed Ubuntu.

I need to recover many of my files in the `/home` folder but there is something that says `Access-Your-Private-Data.desktop` and a `README`which tells me what to do but I cannot run the terminal app for some reason. What to do now?

Comment: "cannot run the terminal app": What app? How exactly are you running it? How exactly does it fail?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you have been a victim of Ransomware. It encrypts your files, and to get access to files, you must pay them. [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ransomware) is the wikipedia page directed to Ransomware. Try exploring some methods. And enable your firewall on every OS/Not 100% safe, but can help for beginner type hackers/.